# How can I get a good approximation of $\sum_{s=1}^\infty x^s\ln(s)\ $?

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series, approximation

How can I get a good approximation of the sum

$$\sum_{s=1}^\infty x^s\ln(s)$$

by hand ?

If I only consider the part of the function, where it is strictly decreasing, I can bound the sum by integrals. But how can I approximate the sum upto this point ?

Comment: Could start by noting the first term is $0$.

Comment: Is $x>0$?  Or not?

Comment: Wolfram alpha saids it is related to polylogarithm...

Comment: In particular, I am interested in the cases $x\approx 1$ and $\approx -1$. The sum converges for $-1<x<1$. The case $x=0$ is obvious.

Comment: It diverges for $x\to1$.

Comment: @SimpleArt A method for $x>0$ would already be nice, but I would like to do it also for $x<0$.

Comment: @Peter I am thinking you can set up a function relationship between $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$.

Comment: For $x\rightarrow -1$, $f(x)$ seems to have a limit. Is this true ?

Comment: Clearly $\sum_{s=1}^\infty(-1)^s\ln(s)$ does not converge, so I don't think $x\to-1$ will either.

Comment: I got $$f(-x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}+\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}-f(x)$$ which doesn't seem like it will converge for $x\to-1$

Comment: @See-WooLee $\displaystyle{-\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,{\partial\mathrm{Li}_{\mu}\left(x\right) \over \partial\mu}}$ ?.

Comment: euler mac laurin will work fine here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $|x|<1$, by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) we have
$$ \log(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-z}-e^{-sz}}{z}\,dz \tag{1}$$
hence
$$ \sum_{s\geq 1}x^s \log(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{s\geq 1}\frac{(e^{-z}-e^{-sz})x^s}{z}\,dz = \frac{x^2}{1-x}\color{purple}{\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-z}}{z(e^z-x)}\,dz}\tag{2}$$
where the purple integral, for a fixed value of $x\in(-1,1)$, is not difficult to approximate through integration by parts, Cauchy-Schwarz or both. It is interesting to notice that such integral representation also provides an analytic continuation of the LHS of $(2)$:
$$ \lim_{x\to -1^+}\sum_{s\geq 1}x^{s}\log(s) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-z}}{z(e^z+1)}\,dz = \log\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tag{3} $$
in agreement with [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: Do you just know about such things by sheer experience, because I'm jealous.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I would say experience *and taste*. Frullani's theorem is one of my all-time favourites, since it provides an integral representation for logarithms, that are ubiquitous in number theory.

Comment: Well, now its my all-time favourite as well.

Comment: Do we have $dz$ in the purple integral ?

Comment: @Peter I assume so?  And in (3), now that you mention it, it should also be a $dz$ I think.

Comment: @Peter: thank you everyone, typos fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$|x|<1$

$$f(x):=\sum_{s=2}^\infty x^s\ln(s)$$

$$f(x)+f(-x)=2x^{-2}\sum_{s=2}^\infty x^{2s}\ln(2s)$$

$$=2x^{-2}\sum_{s=2}^\infty x^{2s}\left(\ln(2)+\ln(s)\right)$$

$$f(x)+f(-x)=2\ln(2)\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}+2\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}$$

So as long as we can approximate it for $x>0$, this relationship allows us to calculate for $x<0$, and vice versa.

Note that for all $x>0$

$$\frac{x^2}{1-x}=\sum_{s=2}^\infty x^s<f(x)$$

It also seems to be fairly good of an approximation as well that is fairly easy.  Try it for a few values?

Comment: These days there are some really unreasonable downvotes. Counteracting.

Comment: I do not think that the equation $f(x)+f(-x)=\cdots$ is correct. The correct equation should be $f(-x)=2f(x^2)-f(x)+2\ln(2)\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$, which fits with numerical examples, for instance $x=0.1$, whereas your equation does not hold.

Comment: @Peter I tried to fix it, but I get $f(x)+f(-x)=2\ln(2)\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}+2\frac{f(x^2)}{x^2}$  Can't see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may at least improve convergence by the following manipulation:
With $f(x) =\sum_{s\geq 1} x^s \log(s)$ we have:
$$(1-x) f(x) = \sum_{s\geq 2} x^s \log(s) - \sum_{s\geq 1} x^{s+1} \log(s) =  \sum_{s\geq 1} x^{s+1} \log(1+\frac{1}{s}) $$ 
You may then use $\log(1+\frac{1}{s}) = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{2s^2} + ...$ to derive
 $$ f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x} \sum_{s\geq 1} x^s \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k s^k} = \frac{x}{1-x} \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \left( \sum_{s\geq 1} \frac{ x^s}{s^k} \right)$$
 $$ f(x) =  \frac{x}{1-x} \left( -\log(1-x) +\sum_{k\geq 2} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sum_{s\geq 1} \frac{ x^s}{s^k} \right)$$
This isolates  the principal singular behavior and you may then find methods (there are more or less explicit but not very useful formulae) for approximating the sums $\sum_{s\geq 1} x^s/s^k$, $k\geq 2$.